# What is Dalvik external memory? Image allocation issues/WeakHashMap issue

Tags: android, dalvik

I'm trying to write an Image cache. I'm using a WeakHashMap to hold the downloaded images and set show them in a list ImageView. However, after a while I run into:

```
02-17 15:13:00.416: D/dalvikvm(11766): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 69% free 3447K/10823K, external 21870K/22699K, paused 16ms
02-17 15:13:00.455: D/dalvikvm(11766): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 69% free 3447K/10823K, external 21870K/22699K, paused 25ms
02-17 15:13:00.463: E/dalvikvm-heap(11766): 116160-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-17 15:13:00.490: E/GraphicsJNI(11766): VM won't let us allocate 116160 bytes
```

After which I am treated with a OutOfMemoryError.

Obviousely I'm running out of "external memory" whatever that is. There is plenty of heap available but that doesn't seem to matter. The GC does not seem to be able to clean up this "external memory" although the only references I have are the weak hash and the imageViews in the list (which should only be a single instance, reused)...

Can somebody please help me shed some light on this matter? What is this external memory I'm running out of? Why isn't the GC cleaning up the old images?

*Edit: I since found out what caused my memory to not be released: WeakHashmap releases entries when the KEYS are no longer referenced, not when the VALUES are not referenced. My main question still remains: what is that external memory?*

Answer (score 0):

I believe base android has 16 MB heap memory, which is used for all of program's objects, including your hashmap, so not much memory for you to use.  Some individual devices with customised ROM may have more space, but by default is 16 MB.  It's actually coded in the Android itself, specifically in file `frameworks/base/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp`:

```
AndroidRuntime::startVm()
...
strcpy(heapsizeOptsBuf, "-Xmx");
property_get("dalvik.vm.heapsize", heapsizeOptsBuf+4, "16m");
//LOGI("Heap size: %s", heapsizeOptsBuf);
opt.optionString = heapsizeOptsBuf;
mOptions.add(opt);
```

You may be able to use `recycle()` method and some other techniques to minimise your app's memory footprint, but if you need to store more than 16 MB of data, then you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not seem to be running out of heap however. As can be seen by the logcat output from above, my heap is almost 70% free, it's that external memory that I'm running out of: '69% free 3447K/10823K, external 21870K/22699K'

Comment: Hm, interesting...  Now reading your question again, I can see it.  I always thought that program's data is stored in the heap

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you're trying to allocate more memory than is available. Even if you have 60% free, if you try to allocate something 61% the size of heap, you'll get a  n Out of Memory Error.